# bash use for loop index in variable name and replace empty value to 0

Tags: bash, for-loop, indexing, escaping, counting

I have 1000 folders from 0000/ to 0999/. Each folder has a specific subfolder of the same name. That is my target folder. The target folder has numerous text files.

What I wish to perform is:

1. For 1000 folders, check multiple specific text files of a specific subfolder to see if the target file contains two specific characters.
2. Count the number of files among specific text files, that has a two specific string AAAAA and BBBBB inside the file. (I used grep for this)
3. Some folders do not even contain some folders. In this case, put 0.
4. Print out the number with folder locations.

This is what I'm writing now using two for-loops. I also added comments of what I want to do above each line of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

NUMDIR=1000   # number of folders from 0000 to 0999
NUM=2

# First for loop, index i
for i in $(seq -f %04g 0 $((NUMDIR-1))); do

     # Create new variable ii that removes 0 from index i,
     # just in case 0 preceding to the number in $i can cause a problem.
     ii=`echo $i | sed 's/^0*//'`

     # Second for loop, index j
     for j in $(seq 4 2 26); do

        # Declare the dynamic valriable using ii and j.
        # The variable contains the number of files 
        # among front-$j-*.txt that has both string AAAAA and BBBBB
        declare count_$ii_$j=$(grep -l AAAAA $(grep -l BBBBB $i/result/list-$NUM/text/front-$j-*.txt) | wc -l)

        # If the variable is empty, then put 0.
        # Some folders does not contain all front-$j=*.txt
        count_$ii_$j=${count_$ii_$j/NULL/0}

        # Print out
        results="$i     $j     $count_${ii}_${j}"
        echo -e "$results" > result.txt
     done
done
```

This script does not work. What I can see is

```
test.sh: line 22: count_$ii_$j=${count_${ii}_${j}/NULL/0}: bad substitution
```

If I remove line 22 and execute, then

```
grep: 0000/result/list-$NUM/text/front-$j-*.txt: No such file or directory
```

It is true that some folders do not have front-$j-*.txt for all $j index. So "No such file or directory" is an expected result.

However, I'm not sure why "bad substitution" occurs. I'm suspecting about the wrong escaping of indices ii and j inside the variable name, because I used ii, not i, to prevent octal value error.

This is also related to the print part, I'm not sure if I'm printing out the target value correctly (I mean, I'm not sure if $count_${ii}_${j} is a proper one inside the "").

In addition, I'm also dubious about this approach/strategy: using $(grep ~~~ | wc -l) inside the command substitution to count the occurrence among target text files. Would it be better to use if structure to count the occurrence of the target file and replace the empty variable with 0 if no target files are found, in the first place?

Comment: Please add a sample directory structure, what the script produces with that sample, and what else you want.  We should not have to figure out how to test your script to help you.

Comment: @Nic3500 directory structure is written in the script. It is $i/result/list-$NUM/text/. $i is from 0000 to 0999, and $NUM is 2. The script does not print anything with "bad substitution" error. There are several text files with the name of "front-$j-*.txt" format, where $j is seq 4 2 26 (all even numbers between 4 and 26). Contents of the text files are not important. Some text file contains the string AAAAA inside, some contain BBBBB, some have both, and some have none of both. I just want to count the number of the text file that contains both AAAAA and BBBBB, per $i and $j.

Comment: Consider using associative arrays.